# Looking for inequalities that relate $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k/(x_k+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$

Tags: inequality

I'm working on a problem about the convergence of series. As such, I would like to ask for inequalities that relate $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k/(x_k+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ where $x_k \ge 0$ for all $k$. My desired inequality is of the form $$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \le f$$

where $f$ is a function depends on $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k/(x_k+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$, and $f$ is independent of $n$.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's wrong with the trivial $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{x_k+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$$?

Comment: Is this what you actually want solve:  [$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges iff $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/(1+a_k)$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2598643/42969) ?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!